# Rails 4 - Admin can create articles with other user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rolify

I'm creating a platform where the Admin can manage everything in the system and one of the properties is create articles with the user_id to the another user.

So the question is what is the best way for make this? because I'm working with devise + cancancan + rolify and currently I'm doing something like that:

I have a Admin login and in my layout I have a navbar and in this navbar I have a collection for recover all the user_ids so this when I select one user_id I'm saving in a session but now I would like to use this user_id to create the articles.

But I don't know if is the best way for doing that.

Just need I little orientation with this topic because I was thinking to create a namespace for separate the admin logic but the admin also can create articles with her own id.

Sorry if the question is basic but I feel I little confuse about what is the best way for doing that.

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the option for admin to be able to switch to any user, and then create articles as that user.

Check [Switch User](https://github.com/flyerhzm/switch_user) gem which works with devise.